# Ограничить ширину выпадающего списка не меняя скрипт

Tags: css

Имеется dropdown, который генерериется при помощи js. Проблема в том, что если содержимое пунктов вылазиет за экран, то у body появляется скролл. Как не меняя скрипт (и, следовательно, inline-стили сделать так, чтобы скролл появлялся у самого dropdown'а? При этом необходимо сохранение минимальной ширины, равной ширене select'а (в примере 270, выставляется скриптом).

Я нашёл только способ, в котором требуется перенесение значение 270 на потомка, что требует либо менять скрипт, либо хардкодить значение ширины с тилях. Как этого избежать?

Всё что прописано в inline-стилях вычисляется и устанавливается скриптом. Это нельзя трогать, но можно переопределять при помощи `!important`.

http://jsfiddle.net/9wguh7oc/6/
Первые 3 списка - как работает сейчас, следующие 3 - что я хочу получить.

```css
html, body { width: 100%; }
*, *:before { box-sizing: border-box; line-height: 20px; }
ul, li { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
.dropdown-menu.open { border: 1px solid; }
ul { border: none; }
li { padding: 2px 8px; }
li:hover { background: silver; }
li.selected { background: #AFCD70; }
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu { float: left; min-width: 100%; }

.bootstrap-select:before { /* Просто для демонмтрации расположения select'а */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    content: "Dropdown (" attr(data-info) ")";
    border: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 270px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
}

#try-to-fix ~ .bootstrap-select {
    right: 0;
    width: auto !important;
}

#try-to-fix ~ .bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#try-to-fix ~ .bootstrap-select[style*="width: 270px;"] .dropdown-menu.open { /* Надо убрать! */
    min-width: 270px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bootstrap-select" style="top: 32px; left: 50px; width: 270px; position: absolute;" data-info="хорошо">
  <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 434px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 60px;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu" style="max-height: 422px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 60px;">
      <li>12345</li>
      <li class="selected">12345</li>
      <li>12345</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bootstrap-select" style="top: 142px; left: 50px; width: 270px; position: absolute;" data-info="хорошо">
  <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 434px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 60px;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu" style="max-height: 422px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 60px;">
      <li>12345</li>
      <li class="selected">12345</li>
      <li>1234567890123456789012345678901234567890</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bootstrap-select" style="top: 252px; left: 50px; width: 270px; position: absolute;" data-info="плохо - вылазиет за эран">
  <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 434px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 60px;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu" style="max-height: 422px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 60px;">
      <li>12345</li>
      <li class="selected">12345</li>
      <li>1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="try-to-fix"></div>

<div class="bootstrap-select" style="top: 362px; left: 50px; width: 270px; position: absolute;" data-info="как было">
  <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 434px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 60px;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu" style="max-height: 422px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 60px;">
      <li>12345</li>
      <li class="selected">12345</li>
      <li>12345</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bootstrap-select" style="top: 472px; left: 50px; width: 270px; position: absolute;" data-info="как было">
  <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 434px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 60px;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu" style="max-height: 422px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 60px;">
      <li>12345</li>
      <li class="selected">12345</li>
      <li>1234567890123456789012345678901234567890</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bootstrap-select" style="top: 582px; left: 50px; width: 270px; position: absolute;" data-info="скролл внутри">
  <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 434px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 60px;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu" style="max-height: 422px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 60px;">
      <li>12345</li>
      <li class="selected">12345</li>
      <li>1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Если в li используете конструкции вида 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890, то у Вас ничего не получится. Стандартно слова ни в коем случае не переносятся. Конечно для этого можно пользоваться [word-wrap](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap).
2. В любом случае рекомендую для li и ul указать max-width

Comment: Я же привёл пример того, что хочу получить. Горизонтальный скролл *внутри списка*. Как в шестром варианте. А сейчас работает как в третьем. Проблема в том, что скрипт прописывает `width` на контейнер, а мне это значение нужно как `min-width` на дочерний элемент. `word-wrap` тут вообще никаким боком. `word-break` - возможно, но от него другие косяки лезут. Со скроллом какие ещё варианты есть?

Comment: Да, вопрос не внимательно прочитал. Вот здесь мои правки: http://jsfiddle.net/Haikson/a9munos9/ 
Добавляем


.bootstrap-select { width: auto!important;right: 0;}

и изменяем
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu { float: left; max-width: 100%; overflow: auto; }

Думаю в этот раз попал.
А поп поводу word-wrap: Свойство word-wrap указывает, переносить или нет длинные слова, которые не помещаются по ширине в заданную область. Вам это свойство не поможет.

Comment: `li { padding: 2px 8px; min-width: 270px; }` - нельзя использовать число 270 в css. Оно может быть разным для разных select'ов и должно браться из inline-стиля контейнера (его туда плагин приписывает).

Comment: Это не суть важно. Выше я написал что именно должно быть изменено для появления скролла. min-width для li проставлен был для меня. Можно убрать.

Comment: "Это не суть важно" - наоборот, это основная проблема, из-за которой я задал вопрос. "Можно убрать" - нельзя убрать. Если убрать, то минимальной ширины не будет.

Comment: <li>1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123...</li>
Как видите, у li изначально не было min-width. Он у родительских блоков
#try-to-fix ~ .bootstrap-select[style*="width: 270px;"] .dropdown-menu.open { /* Надо убрать! */
    min-width: 270px;
}
А проблема с горизонтальным скроллингом всегда возникает не по причине ограничений минимальной ширины, а по причине бесконтрольного роста ширины блока. Соответственно нужно контролировать max-width. http://jsfiddle.net/Haikson/a9munos9/ тот же код, но min-width для li убран. Если же столь важна минимальная ширина, то никто не отменял !important.

Comment: Убрав min-width ты сломал первый пример. Против !important возражений нет. Но надо как-то пропихнуть минимальную ширину из style.width контейнера на те элементы, где она нужна.