# Таблица отказывается растягиваться

Tags: html, css

Есть [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/v7j6yj7g/), при котором таблица отказывается растягиваться. Абсолютное позиционирование блока с текстом относительно блока выше - обязательно, так как этот блок - элемент меню. Нужно, чтобы таблица тянулась от ширины текста

```css
ul {
   float:right;
   background-color: #000;
   height: 40px;
   width: 100px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  
}

.abs {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 560px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.cart_table {
    max-height: 388px;
}

.cart_table tr {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 30px;
    min-width: 410px;
    max-width: 840px;
}

.cart_table tr:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.cart_table td {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class='abs'>
      <table class='cart_table'>
         <tr>
             <td>Текст Текст Текст</td>
             <td>Текст Текст Текст</td>
             <td>Текст Текст Текст</td>
             <td>Текст Текст Текст</td>
             <td>Текст Текст Текст</td>
             <td>Текст Текст Текст</td>
             <td>Текст Текст Текст</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Я запутался.... А можно другими словами как-то объяснить, чего хотите добиться? Какая "таблица" отказывается растягиваться?

Comment: Текст, в нижнем блоке должен переходить на следующую строку только по достижении максимальной ширины, которая задана в стилях - `max-width: 840px;` Таблица с содержимым "Текст"

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Поясни, в чём конкретно проблема, и что требуется получить в результате. Для примера посмотри, как я задавал [вопрос подобного плана](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428584/178988).

Comment: Qwertiy, таблица с содержимым не растягивается по ширине. Нужно сделать так, чтобы растягивалась, не убирая абсолютное позиционирование с родительского `div` и `position: relative` с родительского `li`

Comment: Можно увидеть пример того, что надо получить?

Comment: Qwertiy, получить нужно [следующее](https://jsfiddle.net/v7j6yj7g/1/)

Comment: @Torawhite, просто не используйте таблицу :)

Comment: Grundy, если использовать вёрстку блоками, то они тоже не растягиваются  Вот в чём дело…

Comment: Надо от float отказаться. // Ставь `@` перед ником, чтобы уведомление отправлялось.

Comment: @Qwertiy, тут не во `float` дело, как мне кажется. Тут из-за позиционирования это происходит. Во всяком случае, если убрать `position:relative` у родительского `li` то таблица начинает тянуться, только position:absolute` у дочери уже роли не играет

Comment: @Qwertiy, [вот](https://jsfiddle.net/v7j6yj7g/2/) убрал всё лишнее из стилей таблицы и изменил структуру - вместо списка сделал просто блоками. Всё то же

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно изменить стиль родительского `ul`.
Вместо

```
ul { width: 100px; }
```

используйте

```
ul { width: 100%; }
```

Таким образом Вы получите желаемое...

---

### UPDATE #2

Вот посмотрите вариант ниже. Вам нужно вставить 2 `div`. Первый располагается `relative` относительно `li`. А второй вставлен в первый, именно в нем весь текст с ограничением по длине. Важно для второго `div` обязательно иметь `position: absolute; right: 0;`. Иначе он повлияет на размеры родительского `div`, а тот на все меню.
Я для удобства понимания подкрасил оба `div`. Первый - бордюр цвета aqua; второй - зеленый.

Кажется это делает то, что Вам надо.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
 }
li>div {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 }
li>div>div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
 }
li:hover>div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>menu item 1
    <div>
    <div>
      tLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eget velit et diam blandit pellentesque vulputate et lacus. Mauris ultrices egestas viverra. Curabitur eleifend, enim eget ultrices feugiat, justo sapien pellentesque mauris, eget luctus metus purus in diam. Aliquam malesuada sed velit vitae lacinia. Aenean cursus, urna nec bibendum malesuada, lacus ante rhoncus magna, sed condimentum neque sem tincidunt ante. Etiam efficitur id quam eu gravida. Nunc ut urna vitae turpis varius viverra. Duis ut euismod sapien. Donec est nisi, scelerisque sed placerat id, iaculis in neque. Donec rutrum tempus felis posuere tempus. Maecenas et tempor dui.

Curabitur quis posuere massa. Quisque et urna id dolor bibendum semper. Aenean nec purus id nibh pharetra egestas. Duis et blandit tellus. In pellentesque fermentum ligula. Sed dignissim turpis sit amet feugiat egestas. Phasellus sagittis vitae tortor ac pretium. Morbi venenatis sapien eget augue commodo consequat. Morbi tellus ipsum, bibendum vel erat eget, tempor aliquet ex. Nulla viverra vitae odio eget sollicitudin. Morbi blandit, erat et auctor cursus, risus eros mattis libero, ultrices aliquet odio nisl vel nunc. Donec a lacus gravida neque pellentesque porttitor. In pretium sit amet dui vitae semper. In vel nisl bibendum, ullamcorper turpis vitae, vestibulum magna. Pellentesque luctus finibus egestas.
      </div>
      </div>
      </li>
  <li>menu item 2</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Понятно, тогда встречный вопрос:  Может быть имеет смысл поменять выпадающее содержимое? Есть ли какая-то причина, почему внутри именно `<table>`, да еще с `td` оформленными как `float: left;`?

Comment: cyadvert, пробовал. Всё поменял на `div` структура та же, да и результат тот же блоки - не тянутся. Если убрать абсолютное позиционирование, то всё работает, но ломается вся вёрстка. Почему позиционирование родительского блока так влияет на "пластичность" блоков - впервые столкнулся...

Comment: Добавил вариант в ответ. Посмотрите, похоже на то, что Вам надо?

Comment: cyadvert, спасибо,  но блок не тянется ещё и потому, что у родительского `li` стоит `position: relative;` , а у родительского `ul` - `float:right;` - это также мне нужно чтобы позиционирование произошло относительно блока, по которому кликаем, а сам блок "тёк" по правой стороне

Comment: Еще одно обновление - посмотрите.

Comment: cyadvert, у вас ширина второго дива указана постоянная - 300рх, даже если поменять её на `min-width: 300px` текст всё равно шириной в 300рх остаётся, а должен растянуться по всей ширине страницы

Comment: Т.е., если я Вас правильно понял, у вас меню справа страницы, а выпадающий див должен занимать все простарнство от левого края до конца родительского элемента?

Comment: почти всё, в моём примере ограничение в 840рх стоит по ширине. как только 410 рх стало мало, содержимое тянет блок до максимальных 840рх

Comment: Ну в таком случае я не думаю, что это возможно средствами CSS, потому что `div` либо процентно привязан к родному блоку, а не ко всей старнице, либо должен иметь фиксиврованный размер. Так что думаю Вам надо делать `JS`, который бы рассчитывал фиксированную длину выпадающего блока в зависимости от содержания и расположения родительского элемента меню.

Comment: спасибо.Да, пока только остаётся выставить фиксированную ширину...